# How to combine Rails tag and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog

I have 4 modals on 1 page, each modal has to show product images belonging to a different product. I thought I could use the product.id so that javascript knows which product images to show, but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

In my rails I thought I could do:

```
class="mySlides<%= product.id %>"
```

And then in Javascript I did:

```
getElementsByClassName(`mySlides<%= product.id %>`);
```

But it doesn't work properly. Javascript always grabs the last product.id on the page. How do I correctly insert the <%= product.id %> into a javascript function??

Part of **my view**:

```
<div id="myModal<%= product.id %>" class="productsModal">
 <div class="modal-content">

  <% product.product_images.each.with_index do |product_image, index| %>
    <div class="mySlides mySlides<%= product.id %>">
       <%= image_tag product_image.image.url(:large) %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

  <% product.product_images.each.with_index do |product_image, index| %>
    <div class="column">
      <div style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(<%= index+1 %>)" class="demo demo<%= product.id %>">
        <%= image_tag product_image.image.url(:thumb) %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Part of **JavaScript**:

```
function showSlides(n) {
 var slides = document.getElementsByClassName(`mySlides<%= product.id %>`);
 var dots = document.getElementsByClassName(`demo<%= product.id %>`);
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your javascript is in a separate file, you can add the template handler `.erb`: `myfile.js.erb` to use embed ruby

if your javascript is inside your html view, you can use the rails `javascript_tag` helper (instead of `<script></script>`):

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('mySlides<%= j product.id %>');
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName('demo<%= j product.id %>');
<% end %>
```